# force dd element below dt in a dl HTML list

Tags: html

I do not want my title and data side by side rather above / below:

**Batch Number**

1001

**First Name**

Joey

I tried putting in a "break" with no effect.

```
 <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                Batch Number 
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RebateDetail.BatchNumber)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                First Name
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RebateDetail.FirstName)
            </dd>

        </dl>
```

Or, if I could just get them on the *same* line that would be a start:
[image]

Here is my current style settings:

```
  <style>
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .row {
        display: flex;
    }

    /* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
    .inputColumns {
        flex: 33%;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: bisque;
    }
    .dd {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .dt {
        float: left;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want dd under dt you simply can set margin to 0

```
<style>dd {margin: 0;}</style>
```

If you want them on the same line try this:

```
<style>
  dt {float: left; padding-right: 10px; }
  dd {margin: 0;}
</style>
```

Comment: where do I set that at?

Comment: I will update my question showing my <style> -- sorry I should have done that at first.

Comment: I tried it with a dd and a .dd both with not effect.

Comment: you add css for element not appear on your question. Maybe create fiddle or edit the question?

Comment: Thank you...I added the full CSS I am currently using.

Comment: what are the rules of class="dl-horizontal"? and how your html markup look? and you should use one of the solutions (dd under dt OR dt and dd on the same line)

Comment: I missed the dl-horizontal -- that should not have been there.
Thank you!